# How to install heartbeat?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I need to setup a Linux cluster. For that, heartbeat is used in CentOS. Is there a heartbeat package for Ubuntu as well, and if so, how can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Installing heartbeat can be done easily with Apt:

```
sudo apt-get install heartbeat
```

Through configuring your cluster is highly dependant on what you're are trying to accomplish. By default on Ubuntu, the main configuration file `/etc/ha.d/ha.cf` does not exist and the service will not be started. You must create it yourself. It should identify the nodes in your cluster. For example:

```
node primary
ucast eth0 1.1.1.1
node secondary
ucast eth0 1.1.1.2
```

More information on the `ha.cf` file can be [found here](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Ha.cf).

You'll also need to configure `/etc/ha.d/haresources` with a list of services and the default node to run them on. It can be as simple as:

```
primary my-service
```

Here, `primary` is the name of the default node and `my-service` corresponds to an init script at `/etc/init.d/my-service` More information about the `haresources` file [can be found here](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Haresources).

The file `/etc/ha.d/authkeys` also needs to be created with an auth toke which will be shared on both nodes, like:

```
auth1
1 sha1 d1e6557e2fcb30ff8d4d3ae65b50345fa46a2faa
```

More information on the `authkeys` can be [found here](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Authkeys).

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen that a very big part of the configuration and installation and may be not possible for mentioning here but you can access them from

http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/01/21/installing-a-high-availability-web-server-cluster-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-using-haproxy-heartbeat-and-nginx/

http://blog.romerojunior.com/linux/linux-building-basic-high-availability-infrastructure-for-web-servers/